# Tag Manager Events Not Displaying Showing in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When I enable preview mode the debugger pops up on my site, so the tracking ID seems to be correct.

My tag configuration looks like this:

`type: UA, track-type: event, category: next-question, label: {{Click Element}}, non-interaction: true, GA-settings: {{smb tracking-id}}`

My trigger configuration looks like this:

`trigger-type: click all-elements, this-trigger-fires-on: some-clicks, fire-trigger-when: Click Classes...Contains...next-question`

My other event is a generic page click event.

Both of them trigger in preview mode, but it's not displaying in Google Analytics under /behavior/events.

Would really appreciate any ideas / insights on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that to view events realtime you need to go to RealTime -> Events.
Events under Behaviour only appear after aprox. 24hrs

Answer (score 1):

Install Google Analytics Debugger extension for chrome and check debug logs for GA. It may help.[here's the link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/google%20analytics%20debugger?hl=en-US)

Answer (score 0):

This morning things are working fine and displaying as they should be in behavior/events. I think my analytics settings were cached or something. Maybe next time I'll try logging out and clearing my cookies.